# How to minimise size of .ppt presentations without losing Pictures and Audio in LibreOffice/WPS-office?

Tags: libreoffice, wps-office

I am trying to decrease the size of my .ppt presentations by converting them to .odp/.wps-format, since they take several GBs memory because of

- big pictures and
- audio content in slides.

I would like to store the presentations in smaller space without losing quality i.e. picuters and audio.

### WPS Office

WPS office > Save as > jpg of every slide; which does a very good work in extracting the images; I have not found yet any terminal tool for the task of many .ppt files; the 2-month-old release is alpha but much more stable than the previous ones (> 100 Mb .ppt files) and can render much better .ppt files than LibreOffice presentation.

I already contacted the company about the task with a link to this thread. 
I already sent a related question in their Linux Community of the application but they have not approved it yet [here](http://wps-community.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=4).

### LibreOffice

I do when I have `soffice` in my PATH but get

```
masi@masi:~/$ ppt2odp test.ppt
```

> ```
> Failed to connect to /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin (pid=10643) in 6 seconds.
> Connector : couldn't connect to socket (Success)
> Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
> masi@masi:~/$
> ```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: Is your question about the ppt2odp utility not working, or is it the wider issue described in the title? You've forgotten, I think, to ask the question itself.

Comment: @roaima It is the one in the title, I corrected it. I think LibreOffice cannot do the job at the moment. I think the only option is WPS office but I cannot handle many .ppt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sufficient extraction tool for the task at the moment, so you cannot minimise the presentation size sufficiently for the task requirement.

WPS can render such documents best in Linux.

Currently the only workaround is to manually store at least audio in the presentation.

There should exist reliable tools for the extraction of pictures in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the full question, but I would add that JPG is probably the worst file format because it is designed for photographic (continuous-tone) content, and most people's slides are not contone but vector (small numbers of colours with sharp edges). PNG is a better fit for that purpose, although the new 'webp' format might be even better.

However, my initial reaction would be to export the slides to PDF. PDF files *can* include media (sound, video) but often the exporters don't do it. However the PDF format is better suited to this than a simple image sequence. However, unless very lucky the audio will probably be ignored, and that is bad. Perhaps raise a feature-request with the openoffice folks too?